# How to use time delay in MobileFirst adapters

Tags: timer, delay, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Has anyone tried introducing Delay/timer into the MobileFirst Platform Foundation adapters?
is there anyway to introduce specific amount of delay?

I tried `setTimeout()` but that doesn't work because of window object will not available in Adapter.js

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is the purpose for the time delay?

Comment: Nothing. Wanted introduce some delay on my response. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in the adapter logic, but you can do this in the client logic...

Add the required delay implementation in the adapter procedure request's success callback function so that it won't get processed right away, if that's what you really want to do (which would be strange, but...).

Comment: how can i test request 'timeout' for adapter call of 1min in already working system. Where response is coming in seconds.

Comment: The adapter procedure `timeout` property (in the server and client) refers to the amount of time the server or client will wait before calling the failure callback function. You can't "fake" this in the adapter/client code in order to test it. If you want to test it, you'll need to cause the delay on the network level... check with your IT department.

Comment: yes. that's why I wanted to test the timeout by introducing some delay in adapter procedure

Comment: @VishwasHK try to access the url which is not present so you might get timeout triggered, if u get 404 then create a infinite loop at server procedure function which is not recommended.

Comment: You could possibly make a call out to a simple Java function that has a sleep() call prior to responding.  I've not tried, but should work,